# Group totals with supressed lines in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Have been googling this for a couple of days now and tried various posted solutions, also from Stack Overflow.

I'm making a report, where there is a check on two fields to see if they have been written before. If they are, they are suppressed

***psudo-code:
If {customer} and {date} as previous then suppress.***

This works fine, but I need to make a count for each group. If I use the built in count function, it also counts all suppressed lines and I am running out of ways to search for a way to solve this.
  I have tried to add a custom formula, that counts within each group and resets before next group, but it keeps adding to the total in all the other groups. Have tried it with both ***shared NumberVar*** and ***local NumberVar***

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Figured it out my self. 
  Some of the "posted solutions" to this specific error was not fitted exactly to my needs, so tried back and forth with various solutions.

When making a Running Total Field with group, it only works when it is set to reset with each group. If you encounter this and need help to fix it, then just ask away and I will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `DistinctCount` instead of using regular `Count`.

`DistinctCount` ignores duplicates and only counts records with unique value.

For example, if i have data like

```
customer |   date
---------------------
john     |  01.01.2017
john     |  01.01.2017
john     |  02.01.2017
```

and i use regular `count(customer,date)` the result would be `3`. But if i use `DistinctCount(customer,date)` then the result would be `2`.

Hope it helps